# Converting ipynb to html from Colab not work properly

Tags: html, plot, google-colaboratory, pie-chart

I am using Colab to write a notebook using plotly. Within the notebook everything is fine and I can see the pie, but after converting the notebook into a html I don't see it.

this is  the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
Labels=['No', 'Ex-fumatore', 'Fumatore']
values=[1838, 1293, 574]
fig=px.pie(values = values,names = Labels,hole=.5,title = "Tipologie fumatori In Percentuale")
fig.show()
!jupyter nbconvert --to html /content/pie.ipynb
```

can somebody help me?
Thanks

Comment: I can convert from Colab ipynb to html, but the pie-chart is not shown in the html file